# Any modules which can measure the distance between two modules even through obstacles?

Tags: arduino, rf, bluetooth-low-energy, distance, module

This is for a social distance enforcing project for school. I want to know the distance between Module 1 and Module 2, where each module is worn by a person. Usually ultrasound would be used, but I want to be able to penetrate obstacles. I thought about using radio, but it is very hard to measure distance with these waves as they travel faster than what an Arduino could measure with its clock speed. Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) can only give a rough estimate of distance using a calculation with its RSSI value. What can I do?

I simply want to know whether someone is within a 2m radius of the user. Is BLE the best for this?

Comment: Covid-19 doesn't penetrate walls but radio does.  That means that your system will give false alarms if two people are either side of a wall.

Comment: I realise that... but at the same time, other forms of proximity sensing has only a small detection angle/area in one specific direction - I believe radio, on the other hand, can be transmitted in every direction. To avoid the issue of detecting through walls, the switch which can switch off the sensor could be used. An inelegant solution, but the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing some research and I have found that calculating the distance from the RSSI value of a Bluetooth module would work well in my situation. This is because:

- Even though RSSI is unreliable the further away the source is, I'm
  only interested in using it for close-range purposes. It does not have to be precise to the last centimetre - if you are close, you are close.
- The formula for
  calculating it involves a constant which helps indicate when the
  distance is 1 meter. 1 meter is also the current guideline for the
  distance to keep in public according to the WHO.
- Concrete and bricks may interfere with the reception of a signal, thereby solving the "through-the-wall" problem.

Thank you for all your help - the points raised will still be important to the project.

Comment: I am no expert on Bluetooth but from my understanding is that the RSSI value is a "quality" value rather than signal strength and that it will fall depending on the number of Bluetooth devices and collisions it is detecting as well as the actual signal strength - and the signal strength probably varies from device to device. By all means do the paper exercise but have enough sense to walk away from the project if it doesn't seem feasible. There were several questions on this site back in March when the Covid-19 initially went, ehm, viral (but search isn't finding them for me).

Comment: @Transistor A formula can be used for determining the distance from RSSI. There are many different formulas out there,  but they all take into account environmental factors, i.e. how easily the signal strength can be interfered with. As for signal strength varying with each device, I intend on using an Arduino module which would be worn by each person, and would be the same as each other, so they should emit the same strengths. Also, apparently the COVID-19 API that Google and Apple are working on has something to do with BLE beacons, so looks like it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As you've correctly noticed, in the 2.4 GHz ISM band, you can't assume line-of-sight propagation, so distance measurement through attenuation can't work. Same applies to flight-of-time or other time (difference) of arrival systems between the nodes: the resulting systems aren't solvable without exact knowledge of the environment in terms of radio propagation.

So, nope. This won't work. The only thing that would work is having enough infrastructure (e.g. a receiver every meter) that knows where you are to a high degree of certainty (due to the fact that there'd be enough receivers whose data is centrally collected), and for everyone else.

With a central location registry, it's a software problem to determine distance between people. It'd also be realistic that this central instance has knowledge of walls, windows, and other virus obstacles to make this distance data actually useful.

Anyway, no, with an Arduino and a some radio module, you won't solve this fundamental physical problem.

Realistically, the problem you're trying to solve doesn't solve that much:  an exact distance isn't *that* relevant to infection risk, compared to things like *duration*, *type*, *intensity* of interaction, and the state of the carrier and suspectible person. In other words: as already practiced everywhere on this world (aside from very few countries with strange governments), carrying masks and discouraging risky behaviour is the way to go. For after-the-fact contact tracing, much rougher contact information is sufficient.

In fact, it shows that countries where the Corona contact tracing apps collect *less* fine data, they are far better adopted and thus useful, then where information is centrally collected and could hence be used to trace people.

So, as a very typical engineer's approach, you're trying to solve a 90% human, 10% technical problem with a 100% technical approach.

Comment: I would go with an overhead camera in the classroom that would detect people on the image and calculate the distances between them

Comment: I understand what you are saying - there are better ways to deal with the problem than merely keeping at a distance. What if we were somehow be able to record everyone that anyone has been in contact with, and the length of time taken? Would this be feasible then?

Comment: I, for one, welcome our Orwellian Overlord, @Nazar.  (I certainly wouldn't do that. If that's what it takes to enforce in-classroom, chances are *extremely* slim that distancing won't break down around the corner. Also, the measure is really in no good relation to what it allows to do: If that is necessary for it to be safe to send students to class, then by all means, keep the classrooms shut and the students at home)

Comment: @Hari5000 you'll want to look up the German Corona Warn App. Yes, this is feasible, for > 15 Million users.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to somehow find a way to continue with this project - it is a team effort, and it wouldn't be nice to tell everyone that it was pointless to work on the idea.

Comment: @Hari5000 look. up. the. German. Corona Warn App.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, didn't notice at first, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be overspecifying the problem.  Inability to penetrate barriers could be a plus for social distancing purposes, since being close to someone but with a barrier between you is even better than maintaining a specified spacing.  If ultrasound can't penetrate the barrier, it's highly likely droplets and aerosol will behave similarly.  Note that this solution implies that the user devices determine distance themselves, and any infrastructure is used only for data collection.